# How to create 3 simple functions to return isolated chars, to return duplicated chars and to return string with #comment removed?

Tags: python, function, loops, recursion, duplicates

Function1: `remove_all_dup('abbcdddeabcc')` should return `'aceab'`

Function2: `remove_no_rep('abbcdddeabcc')` should return `'bbdddcc'`

Function3: `remove_py_com('"abbc#d: " not fun#ction')` should return `'"abbc#d: " not fun'`

(Note that `#` is only not removed when inside "" and these must be and are commonly used in pairs.)

These kind of exercises are really killing me because it has been many months around them in despair. Even though a solution was provided with a while loop inside a while loop, my logic can't follow. But maybe it will all make sense if I see different ways of solving these.

Please help me out.

This is what I've done so far for the last function:

```
def remove_py_com(txt):
    for letter in txt:
        if '"' not in txt or txt.find("#")<txt.find('"'):
            return txt[:txt.find("#")]
        elif "#" not in txt:
                return txt
        elif "#" in txt and '"' in txt:
            after=txt[txt.find("#"):]
            for letter in after:
                if after[1:].find("#")<after.find('"'):
                    return txt
                    for bullshit in after[after.find('"'):]:
                        txt=after[after.find('"'):] # so python go to top and check tail-txts again and again... but problem is "after" is not going for what's coming after the "quote"
# Maybe I can create 2 functions for this in a function to make it all clear for the mentally retarded like myself
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: def remove_py_com(txt):
    for letter in txt:
        if '"' not in txt or txt.find("#")<txt.find('"'):
            return txt[:txt.find("#")]
        elif "#" not in txt:
                return txt
        elif "#" in txt and '"' in txt:
            after=txt[txt.find("#")-1:]
            for letter in after:
                if after.count('#')==1 and after[1:].find("#")<after[1:].find('"'):
                    return txt           
                    
#remove_py_com('"def f(#): " f function')

Comment: @UgaBuga, as you no-doubt noticed, code in comments is not readable. You should edit the question and include code there. If you indent the code with four spaces, it will format it nicely.

Comment: @Nicholas Hunter Thank you. It took time but I figure out how to format all. My function only works when there's no string in the string or if there is a string but # comes before it and if there's # inside the string and no # comes when the string ends.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I guess it's formatting on the post is working now but showing my code seems to only show how stupid I am because and I know I can't keep up with my code. I have to find a way that can repeatedly find if there's a # in between the strings (if it's inside it's to be ignored) I really want to not use while loops ...

Comment: This is 3 questions at once- please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the functions 1 and 2 you can consider defining function that computes whether each each character in the string has a duplicate neighbour or not.

```py
def find_duplicates(s):
    # compare each element with the next element
    comparisons = [i==j for i, j in zip(s[1:], s[:-1])]

    # a character is a duplicate if it is equal to one of it's neighbours
    is_duplicate = [i or j for i, j in zip([False] + comparisons, comparisons + [False])]
    return is_duplicate
```

This should return a list with `True` or `False`. For example:

```py
>>> find_duplicates("abbcdddeabcc")
[False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, True, True]
```

You can then use this function to filter your original string.

```py
def remove_all_dup(s):
    is_duplicate = find_duplicates(s)
    return "".join([ch for i, ch in enumerate(s) if not is_duplicate[i]])


def remove_no_rep(s):
    is_duplicate = find_duplicates(s)
    return "".join([ch for i, ch in enumerate(s) if is_duplicate[i]])
```

This should return:

```py
>>> remove_all_dup('abbcdddeabcc')
'aceab'

>>> remove_no_rep('abbcdddeabcc')
'bbdddcc'
```